# Angular - onfig.service.ts:11:1 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript

In my Angular-11 config.service, I used:

```
var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

I got this error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'. 10 var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

Then when I changed it to:

```
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}');
```

This error becomes:

> src/app/core/services/config.service.ts:11:1 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

> 11 this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}');

Then "this" is underlined

> object is possibly 'undefined'

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Please share the full declaration of the `ConfigService` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right approach:

```
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')!) || {};
```

It is because:

- Although `JSON.parse(null)` is invalid from the TS point of view, it is still valid and will result in `null`
- Thus `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')!)` will either return object in localstorage or `null`
- Finally with `|| {}`, you state, that it will definitely return something

Comment: It still underlines this., and when when I point the mouse to it, I got this: object is possibly 'undefined'

Comment: What is the type of `currentUser`?

Comment: How and where do I know the type of currentUser? I just declared: var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something more verbose:

```
const currentUserFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('currentUser') as string; 
const currentUser = !!currentUserFromStorage ? JSON.parse(currentUserFromStorage) : {};
```

Comment: It still underlines : "this."

Comment: Maybe your tool is broken, or maybe, you are not in a class.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCuAnRBTMUCqEWIGKJAFsBlKERAQwHMUYBeGAGxGAsdPOpQDoaoBJKCkIAKAOQJkaTNkRiAlDAoQY0RAEswVANwwAUKEixJqdFhz0YAQisnp5vARJlKNGAH4YAKWIB5AHLcAA4UiNgidmay+EQcriiKAFwwAN4Avtp6BuAQIIw8zFQRSKYyOPKZekA